# Maximal SHA-1 Hash Performance Tips in Java

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, hash, sha1

I'm writing a Java library that needs to compute SHA-1 hashes.  During a common task, the JVM spends about 70% of its time in `sun.security.provider.SHA.implCompress`, 10% in `java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate`, and 2% in `sun.security.provider.ByteArrayAccess.b2iBig64`.  (According to NetBeans profiler.)

I can't seem to get the Google search keywords right to get relevant results.  I'm not very familiar with the SHA-1 hash algorithm.  How can I get the most performance out of an SHA-1 `MessageDigest`?  Is there a certain chunk size I should be digesting, or multiples of certain sizes I should try?

To answer some questions you're thinking about asking:

- Yes, I'm digesting as I read the files (`MessageDigest.update`), so bytes are only digested once.
- The SHA-1 digests are being used as checksums, usually for files that need to be zlib/inflated.
- No, I can't use a different hash.
- Yes, I know zlib already uses checksums, but external requirements specify the use of SHA-1 hashes on top of that.  I can't come up with a good reason why (+1 if you can) :-)

Comment: If it is IO on your local computer that needs to do this work, I suggest investing in a SSD disk, since I suspect that actually reading the files from HDD is a bottleneck here.

Comment: I've already done the most I can to optimize I/O.  I've already looked into various IO optimizations, and the profiler says that IO takes just as much time as digesting.  I'm pretty sure I can't do any better with IO

Comment: Java is (was) slow compared with C/C++, but in some task, it is a tad quicker. If you have access to a C/C++ implementation of your algorithm, then do a comparison. If java is significantly slower, there is probably room for improvement, but if they're almost equal, there is probably small chance of improvement. (I did a comparison to both C and Ds when I had a bunch of math to do, and it turned out that my java version was the quickest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHA-1 has a block size of 64 bytes, so multiples of that are probably best; otherwise the implementation will need to copy partial blocks into buffers.

Are you running on a multi-core computer?  You could run the zlib decompression and SHA-1 hashing in separate threads, using something like `java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue` to hand off each decompressed 64-byte block from the one thread to the other.  That way you can have one core hashing one block while another core is decompressing the next block.

(You could try one of the other `BlockingQueue` implementations that has some storage capacity, but I don't think it'd help much.  The decompression is much faster than the hashing, so the zlib thread would quickly fill up the queue and then it'd have to wait to put each new block, just like with the `SynchronousQueue`.)

I know you said you've optimized I/O already, but are you using asynchronous I/O?  For maximum performance you don't want to hash one block and *then* ask the OS to read the next block, you want to ask the OS to read the next block and then hash the one you already have while the disk is busy fetching the next one.  However, the OS probably does some readahead already, so this may not make a big difference.

But beyond all that, a cryptographic hash function is a complex thing; it's just going to take time to run.  Maybe you need a faster computer.  :-)

Comment: It would be nice if they had used a non-cryptographic hash as a checksum instead of a cryptographic one on top of the CRC used in zlib.  Asynchronous I/O would be a good idea if I wasn't targeting the performance of my library, not really the performance of this particular test of checking a lot of files.  It did get me thinking about how I can make the library I'm designing more multithread-friendly, however.  I think I was just surprised that calculating checksums takes longer than file I/O, that the designers of the programs that use the files I'm working with just made a weird choice

Comment: Well, presumably they want the extra collision resistance that a cryptographic hash provides; otherwise there'd be no added value over the CRC that zlib does already.

Comment: And sequential file access isn't all that slow on modern hard drives.  I have some 5900rpm "green" drives that average more than 100MB/sec over the whole drive, peak 150MB/sec at the edge.  Compared to a relatively slow algorithm like SHA-1, that's not bad.

Comment: You would think they want the extra collision resistance... but what if I said there are only about 57000 unique objects?  Wouldn't CRC32 cover that with super low collision rates?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can call out to native code written in C. There must be a ton of super optimized SHA1 libraries available.

Comment: Ewww... that sounds like a lot of work.  And I have no idea if maybe I just need to send the right size buffers to the digester.  That's really what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching the file processing to a Memory Mapped file?  Performance for those tends to be significantly faster than regular IO and NIO.

Comment: The SHA-1 digests are being used as checksums, usually for files that need to be zlib/inflated.  Actually, I'm using `DirectByteBuffer`s because most of the files need to be inflated before the checksum can be computed.  Looking at the call stack from the profiler, the digest engine uses a method that, when sent a buffer that has no array (a non-heap-buffer) it actually copies the contents of the direct buffer into a new, local, heap, primitive byte array.  In fact, it even optimizes that primitive byte buffer based on the operating system and CPU L1 cache size.  Depending on the JVM.

Comment: It would be nice if sun's JRE provided a digester that worked with `MappedByteBuffers`.  Do you know of one I can distribute with the library?  It would be even better if java.util.zip worked with `MappedByteBuffer`s.  I mean, it already works in native memory!  Maybe I'll put in an RFE...